# Why would AllocateStreamingResources fail with error code 0x80004005?

Tags: windows, winapi, audio, ms-media-foundation, dmo

I'm trying to get the demo for the AEC DMO working ([found here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/audio/aecmicarray)). It works, but only on certain machines. On those machines it fails on, [AllocateStreamingResources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms785922(v=vs.85)) fails with error code 0x80004005. The exact line of code is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/340d6c8c537919663cb122d1a3cf76bed91c06f8/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/audio/aecmicarray/AecSDKDemo.cpp#L383).

I ran dependency walker on the .exe the demo code produces and on the machines it fails on, no dependency failures were detected. The code just doesn't do anything after reporting AllocateStreamingResources failed.

I'm running with the following parameters: -out mic_out.pcm -mod 0 -spkdev 0 -micdev 0.

All machines have functional speakers and microphones. Sound is playing out of the speakers when I run the application. Any thoughts?

Comment: `It works, but only on certain machines. On those machines it fails on`   Which machines are successful and which machines are failing? `0x80004005` means Unspecified failure.  I cannot reproduce on my machine(windows 10 20H2).

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT: thanks for your response. They are Intel NUCs, with a Windows 10.0.17763 image for a product we ship. The image is relatively locked down feature-wise (I can get exact specifics on that if it'd help), but are there features of Windows that can be disabled that'd cause the DMO to error out in this way? I'm able to get Windows Media Player to launch and play a WAV file (which is how I got sound out on these devices) on these machines just fine, for example. So I know that much works. Any and all other machines I've tested the example code on, it works, all but these NUCs.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT: I've made a bit more progress in terms of understanding the nature of the problem. It is NOT the base image, but it seems to be the Azure Kinect we've got connected to the NUC as the microphone. Removing the Azure Kinect and using an off-the-shelf USB or jack-based microphone, it works on these machines. Is it possible there's some limiting factor in terms of the USB bus + the Azure Kinect that's causing the DMO to fail? As I said, I'm able to get at least one other USB microphone to work.

Comment: The problem is likely to be related to the devices you are using the DMO with. Media type details, device capabilities and so on. It is hard to identify the actual cause but eventually you need to capture it. `AllocateStreamingResources` is just a method when initialization of operation happens, the method does not tell much about the error.

Comment: Just a blind guess but maybe you're trying to take off with it and an audio device which is not capable to operate at sampling rates 22050 and below.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT: Let me grab this opportunity to lobby you to lobby the powers that be at Microsoft to not have the Windows API generate Unspecified Failures. Try googling this error code - thousands, possibly millions of hours have been lost trying to troubleshoot issues related to it. If we were told what the actual issue was (Windows must know), that could probably have been substantially reduced. Thanks, getting off my soap box now :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved similar problem by:

1. Uninstall audio device in the Device Manager
2. Reboot